# A question on uniform algebras

Tags: functional-analysis

Let
$A$ be a uniform algebra on a compact metric space
$X$

Why the necessary condition for
$A$
to be
$C(X)$(the algebra of all complex-valued continuous functions on
$X$) is that the maximal ideal space of
$A$
be
$X$

Comment: Do you want to know why the maximal ideal space of $C(X)$ is $X$?

Comment: I want to know maximal ideal space of A be X is the necessary condition

Comment: Strange formulation! The statements "*Object $x$ has property $p$" and "*A necessary condition for $y=x$ is that $y$ has property $p$*" are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jochen, mentioned, you are asking in a very convoluted way, to show that

> the maximal ideal space of $C(X)$ is $X$.

This is standard, and comes from the (homeomorphic) correspondence $$
\text{maximal ideals}\ \leftrightarrow \ \text{characters}\ \leftrightarrow\ \text{points in $X$}.
$$
You find the maximal ideals as the kernels of the characters. And you find the characters as the point evaluations. The weak$^*$-topology on the characters corresponds with the pointwise convergence of functions.